# to run nodejs script in linux using nodejs cron module

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to run  nodejs script in Linux using nodejs cron module with cron pattern = 0 00 05 * * *   but instead of running once at 5 AM it is running twice once at 1 AM and again at 5 AM

What cron pattern should I use to run once at 5 AM every day

Comment: Your pattern is ok, show us your code. If you want you can try this one `00 00 05 * * 1-5` but is very similar

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) module, Please mention which module you are using for cron

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://crontab.guru/ - I use this resource all the time.

From that site, and in general from my experience with Cron expressions, what you want is:

```
0 5 * * * /path/to/your/script
```

The pattern works out to:

0 - at 00 minutes
5 - at hour 05
* - every day of the month
* - every month of the year
* - every day of the week